# Chartjs scaleLabel position

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Trying to get the Y axis scale labels to look like the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgoxX.png), to be position on top of the scale and not rotated.

scale options currently look like:

```
    scales: {
  yAxes: [{
    id: 'temp',
    scaleLabel: {
      display: true,
      labelString: '°C'
    },
    type: 'linear',
    position: 'left'
  }, {
    id: 'ppm',
    scaleLabel: {
      display: true,
      labelString: 'ppm',
    },
    type: 'linear',
    position: 'left',
    ticks: {
      stepSize: 500
    }
  }, {
    id: '%',
    scaleLabel: {
      display: true,
      labelString: '%',
    },
    type: 'linear',
    position: 'right',
    ticks: {
      max: 100,
      min: 0
    }
  }]
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3a7qvtwz/2/

Comment: scale label position can be changed as below,xAxes: [ {
                                    scaleLabel: {
                                        display: true,
                                        labelString: 'Frequency Hz'                                        
                                    },
                                    position: 'top'
                                }]

Comment: @Buminda No this won't work. The 'position' in your answer is for entire y-axe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api) that offers a range of hooks that may be used for performing custom code. To draw the scale labels on top of the different `yAxes` in your code sample, the `afterDraw` hook could be defined as follows. It uses [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.fillText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillText) to draw text directly on the `canvas`.

```
plugins:[{
  afterDraw: chart => {
    var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.font = "bold 14px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
    var y = 50;

    ctx.textAlign = 'left';        
    ctx.fillText('CO2', 5, y);
    ctx.fillText('°C', 46, y);

    ctx.textAlign = 'right';
    ctx.fillText('%', chart.chart.width - 10, y);
    ctx.restore();
  }
}],
```

Please have a look at your amended [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/39Lmrf0k/2/)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3706

It's still not supported,but there is a way to workaround.

title: {
                display: true,
                text: ['realTile','leftScalelabel...............................

many space.......................................................
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        rightScalelabel']
            },