# How to change position of y-axis label from left to top?

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

How to change position of y-axis label from left to top with chart.js?

[The chart with the y-axis label on the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3x7g.png)
[The chart with the y-axis label on the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGcXr.png)

Here's my current code of y-axis:

```
yAxes: [{
  gridLines: {
    display: false
  },
  scaleLabel: {
    display: true,
    labelString: 'Y Axis Label',
    fontSize: 20    
  }
}]
```

Comment: did you had the solution for this https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3x7g.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62112874/2358409